# No embeds API access - iframely

Tags: javascript, html, oembed

I am working on a project, and a key point of it, is to display links as embeded content. After looking around I found iframely.

One of their [methods](https://iframely.com/docs/embedjs) is to use embed.js, like this:

```
iframely.load(containerElement, 'http://yoururl.here');
```

or like this:

```
<a href="http://yoururl.here" data-iframely-url>yoururl.here</a>
```

Doing both like this, I get a "Preview not available. No embeds API Access" error.

[Here is a jsfiddle of the code](https://jsfiddle.net/btt9hssr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an iframely API-Key.
[See API Documentation](https://iframely.com/docs/iframely-api)

[Get an API-Key here](https://iframely.com/signup)